# How to update UI in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I'm reading a list from my local Json file and i'm trying to sort the list by either number or alphabet and update the UI depend on user choice.

I'm able to filter the List but not really sure how to update the UI when a user press a either button so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion.

Right now, I just called one function in my FutureBuilder and not sure how to modify it.

```
class _SawnawkScreenState extends State<SawnawkScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isSwitched = false;

    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: SortbyNumber(), // Need to do something here
        builder: (context, data) {
          if (data.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text("${data.error}"));
          } else if (data.hasData) {
            var items = data.data as List<SawnAwkModel>;

            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: items == null ? 0 : items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                  return SawnawkCardWidget(
                    id: items[index].id!,
                  );
                });

          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
        children: [
          SpeedDialChild(
              child: Icon(Icons.sort_by_alpha_outlined),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              label: 'Sort by alphabet',
              onTap: () => {
                    print('sort by alphabet'),

                    //Do something here
             
                  }),

         SpeedDialChild(
              child: Icon(Icons.sort_by_number),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              label: 'Sort by number',
              onTap: () => {
                    print('sort by number'),

                    //Do something here
             
                  }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<List<SawnAwkModel>> SortbyNumber() async {
  final jsondata =
      await rootBundle.rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/sawnawk_data.json');
  final list = json.decode(jsondata) as List<dynamic>;

  return list.map((e) => SawnAwkModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
}


Future<List<SawnAwkModel>> SortbyAlphabet() async {
  final jsondata =
      await rootBundle.rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/sawnawk_data.json');
  final list = json.decode(jsondata) as List<dynamic>;

  List<SawnAwkModel> profileList =
      list.map((e) => SawnAwkModel.fromJson(e)).toList();

  profileList.sort((a, b) {
    return a.titleFalam.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.titleFalam.toLowerCase());
  });

  return profileList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the UI, the code that changes the UI must be in a `setState({})` function. In your case, try this:

```dart
SpeedDialChild(
  child: Icon(Icons.sort_by_alpha_outlined),
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  label: 'Sort by alphabet',
  onTap: () => {
    print('sort by alphabet'),

    setState({
      final sorted = await SortbyAlphabet()
      //update widget contents with sorted value above
    })
        
}),
```

Your current code if difficult to update the UI, I suggest storing the ListView.builder items in a variable accessible by the function you want to use to update the UI, and change the contents there, like this:

```
class _SawnawkScreenState extends State<SawnawkScreen> {
    bool isSwitched = false;
    List items = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: SortbyNumber(), // Need to do something here
        builder: (context, data) {
          if (data.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text("${data.error}"));
          } else if (data.hasData) {
            items.addAll(data.data as List<SawnAwkModel>);

            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: items == null ? 0 : items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return SawnawkCardWidget(
                    id: items[index].id!,
                  );
                });
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
        children: [
          SpeedDialChild(
              child: Icon(Icons.sort_by_alpha_outlined),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              label: 'Sort by alphabet',
              onTap: () async {
                    setState({
                      print('sort by alphabet'),
                      final newItems = await SortbyAlphabet();
                      items.clear();
                      items.addAll(newItems);
                    })
                  }),
          SpeedDialChild(
              child: Icon(Icons.sort_by_number),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              label: 'Sort by number',
              onTap: () async {
                   setState({
                      print('sort by number'),
                      final newItems = await SortbyNumber();
                      items.clear();
                      items.addAll(newItems);
                    })
                  }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<List<SawnAwkModel>> SortbyNumber() async {
  final jsondata =
      await rootBundle.rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/sawnawk_data.json');
  final list = json.decode(jsondata) as List<dynamic>;

  return list.map((e) => SawnAwkModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
}

Future<List<SawnAwkModel>> SortbyAlphabet() async {
  final jsondata =
      await rootBundle.rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/sawnawk_data.json');
  final list = json.decode(jsondata) as List<dynamic>;

  List<SawnAwkModel> profileList =
      list.map((e) => SawnAwkModel.fromJson(e)).toList();

  profileList.sort((a, b) {
    return a.titleFalam.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.titleFalam.toLowerCase());
  });

  return profileList;
}
```

Comment: Could you please help me more on how to update the UI?. I've already added setState inside the function but I'm kinda stuck so not sure what to do.

Comment: You need to have a variable that can be updated with the new items to reflect the different sort. Try this: where you have ```var items = data.data as List<SawnAwkModel>;``` then move the variable below the ```isSwitched``` variable and set it as and empty list like this: ``` var items = [];```  . Where that variable currently is in the FutureBuilder, add this line above: ```items.clear();```, then change the variable to ``` items.addAll(data.data as List<SawnAwkModel>); ```

Comment: I included the code I am talking about in my answer. Try that.

Comment: I made a mistake on where the items and isSwitched variables should be stored, I just fixed it in the answer.

Comment: I'm getting an error on "await"  final newItems  = await SortbyAlphabet(); . any idea?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: it saying "The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'."

Comment: That is because the function has to indicate it has asynchronous calls. I forgot this in the code I sent. Try this:
```onTap: () async {
                    setState({
                      print('sort by alphabet'),
                      final newItems = await SortbyAlphabet();
                      items.clear();
                      items.addAll(newItems);
                    })
                  }),
```

Comment: I just updated my answer.

Comment: ok, but the UI is still not updating. it's that might be because of this?  body: FutureBuilder( future: SortbyNumber(),

Comment: Is this on GitHub? I would like to run it and try to reproduce the issue

Comment: If not, update the question with the code from the entire file you are having this problem with, the code for SawnAwkModel, and the json files with the data.

Comment: Oh It did change the order to either by Number or Alphabet but I've to scroll the List/View manually first for some reason. After only that it update the sort. any idea why it might be?

Comment: It must have something to do with how the ListView.builder works. I don't know. I can help if you use regular ListView.

Comment: Sure bro. I can use any thing, I just want this to work. thanks

Comment: Let me know hoe it goes. Please research how it works and the differences of ListView and ListView.builder. Basically .builder renders on demand and only what is visible, but that is an oversimplification.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70202810/15215450 for example on ValueListenable Builder

Please refer to the below code

```
final ValueNotifier<List> items = ValueNotifier([]);

floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
        children: [
          SpeedDialChild(
              child: Icon(Icons.sort_by_alpha_outlined),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              label: 'Sort by alphabet',
              onTap: () => {
                    print('sort by alphabet'),

                    //Do something here
                    items.value.clear();
                    items.value = await SortbyAlphabet();
                    items.notifyListeners();
             
                  }),

         SpeedDialChild(
              child: Icon(Icons.sort_by_number),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              label: 'Sort by number',
              onTap: () => {
                    print('sort by number'),

                    //Do something here
                    items.value.clear();
                    items.value = await SortbyAlphabet();
                    items.notifyListeners();
             
                  }),
        ],
      ),


      ValueListenableBuilder(
            valueListenable: isSwitched,
            builder: (context, snapshot, child) {

            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: items.value == null ? 0 : items.value.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                  return SawnawkCardWidget(
                    id: items.value[index].id!,
                  );
                });

            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
  late Future<dynamic> _future;

  @override
   void initState() {
    _future = getDoctors();
  }

    class _SawnawkScreenState extends State<SawnawkScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        bool isSwitched = false;
    
        return Scaffold(
          body: FutureBuilder(
           future: _future, // Need to do something here
            builder: (context, data) {
              if (data.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text("${data.error}"));
              } else if (data.hasData) {
                var items = data.data as List<SawnAwkModel>;
    
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: items == null ? 0 : items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    
                      return SawnawkCardWidget(
                        id: items[index].id!,
                      );
                    });
    
              } else {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          ),
          floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
            children: [
              SpeedDialChild(
                  child: Icon(Icons.sort_by_alpha_outlined),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  label: 'Sort by alphabet',
                  onTap: () => {
                        print('sort by alphabet'),
    
                        //Do something here

                      setState(() {.  // call setstate to refresh futurebuilder
                         _future = SortbyAlphabet();
                     }),
                 
                      }),
    
             SpeedDialChild(
                  child: Icon(Icons.sort_by_number),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  label: 'Sort by number',
                  onTap: () => {
                        print('sort by number'),
    
                        //Do something here
                 
                      }),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    Future<List<SawnAwkModel>> SortbyNumber() async {
      final jsondata =
          await rootBundle.rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/sawnawk_data.json');
      final list = json.decode(jsondata) as List<dynamic>;
    
      return list.map((e) => SawnAwkModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
    }
    
    
    Future<List<SawnAwkModel>> SortbyAlphabet() async {
      final jsondata =
          await rootBundle.rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/sawnawk_data.json');
      final list = json.decode(jsondata) as List<dynamic>;
    
      List<SawnAwkModel> profileList =
          list.map((e) => SawnAwkModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
    
      profileList.sort((a, b) {
        return a.titleFalam.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.titleFalam.toLowerCase());
      });
    
      return profileList;
    }
```

Comment: hi bro, I'm getting LateInitialzationError on _future . I've changed it to Future<dynamic>? _future; and I don't get any errror anymore but the list is not loading and I'm only seeing PorgressIndicator spinning endlessly. Any idea?

Comment: DId u add initstate ?

Comment: you should initialize on initstate itself ?

Comment: Yes, I added initstate but it's still loading endlessly.

Comment: share me ur anydesk id

Comment: Could you share me your email or pls contact me at jsianguk@gmail.com and I'll send you the links. thanks

Comment: Still not solved ?

Comment: do u hav skype ?

Comment: Ok pls add me,

live:.cid.3fb6e0d64aba7e36

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246803/discussion-between-anandh-krishnan-and-aasenomad).